# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven'

Tags: java, xml, spring, weblogic

I'm getting this error everytime i try to deploy my application on Oracle WebLogic:

```
Message icon - Error weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven'.:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven'.

Message icon - Warning Errors were encountered while performing this operation
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

      <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="test_DS" />

      <task:annotation-driven />
      <context:annotation-config/>

      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

      <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">
            <property name="transactionManagerName" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" />
      </bean>

     
      <bean id="baseTransactionProxy"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
            abstract="true">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                  <props>
                        <prop key="insert*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                  </props>
            </property>

      </bean>
</beans>
```

I tried various solution, but it doesn't exist there's any issue with my url declaring at the top. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that you think there is a global declaration for `task:annotation-driven`, despite the fact that the error message says there isn't? Or is it just that you have no idea what the error message means?

Comment: I was suspecting it was a missing beans declaration but it doesn't seems to be the case. No idea about the global declaration.

Comment: Perhaps you have hidden characters in your original file, have you checked it?